# Не пойму задание Facebook Hacker Cup 2013

Tags: c++, delphi, массивы

https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=494433657264959&round=185564241586420
или
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1575529/

в первом рядку ответом будет 8... но генератор чисел уже использует это число (в первых k числах)

моя реализация генератора:

```
   function InitM(Ak: Int64): TArray<Int64>;
    begin
      SetLength(Result, Ak);
      Result[0] := -1; // это для следящей функи...
      Result[Ak - 1] := a;
      while Ak > 2 do
      begin
        Dec(Ak);
        Result[Ak - 1] := (b * Result[Ak] + c) mod r;
      end;
      TArray.Sort<Int64>(Result);
    end;
```

Вопрос: Что требует задание?
Я понял так: первые k элементов массива m. и если первые k элементов равны [0, 5, 3, 6] то следующими будут наименьшие неотрицательные числа т. е. [1, 2, 4, 7, 8...]
Но похоже Я ошибаюсь

Comment: @ADR, а в чем вопрос? 

Меня по ссылке не пускает, хочет какой-то регистрации.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Сейчас дополню

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тонкость, на которой многие спотыкаются, в этой фразе:

> the minimum non-negative integer which is *not* contained in the previous *k* values of `m`.
>
> минимальное неотрицательное число, не входящее в **предыдущие** *k* элементов массива `m`.

т.е. для вашего примера, если первые k элементов равны [0, 5, 3, 6], то:

- m[4] = 1 (предыдущие элементы [0, 5, 3, 6])
- m[5] = 0 (предыдущие элементы [5, 3, 6, 1])
- m[6] = 2 (предыдущие элементы [3, 6, 1, 0])
- m[7] = 3 (предыдущие элементы [6, 1, 0, 2])
- m[8] = 4 (предыдущие элементы [1, 0, 2, 3])
- m[9] = 1 (предыдущие элементы [0, 2, 3, 4])
- m[10] = 0  (предыдущие элементы [2, 3, 4, 1])

Таким образом `m = [0, 5, 3, 6, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0]`